# How do I discard transparency channel when encoding files with bpgenc?

Tags: png, alpha-channel, bpg

Sometimes png pictures contain redundant alpha channel. While this is usually not an issue, for libbpg it triggers more complicated mode which is not compatible with fast x265 encoding or with decoding by old libbpg decoder.

WebP command line encoder, for example, contains `-noalpha` option to explicity discard transparency infromation. How do I do the same for `bpgenc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply my patch to libbpg: https://gist.github.com/vi/f42e466c9744371b0c2e

After that `-noalpha` option should become available, turning transparency in PNG images into black background and enabling `-e x265`.

Comment: (I've already tried submitting the patch upstream, but got no reply)